# Sequence of polynomials $P_n(z)$ with $e^{P_n(z)}$ converging uniformly on compacta to $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I bumped into the following problem, but I'm not sure I know the appropriate way to tackle it.

> Is there a sequence of polynomials $P_n(z)$ such that $e^{P_n(z)}$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ to $z$?

This seems too good to be true, because if there is such a sequence, then the derivative series also converges uniformly on compacta, giving $|P_n'(z) e^{P_n(z)}-1| \to 0$ for large $n$. So it seems like $e^{P_n(z)}$ would converge to something with poles, unless the polynomials are degree one, which seems like it shouldn't be too bad to find a contradiction in. Would this be a fruitful approach, or is there a slicker way?

Comment: Say $f$ is entire and $f$ has no zero on the circle $|z|=1$. What is $1/(2\pi i)\int_{|z|=1}f'(z)/f(z)\,dz$?

Comment: Btw, is "unicompactly" a real word?

Comment: Hm, so we could figure out how many roots $P_n'(z)$ has in the unit disk, and then by unicompact convergence, it would be the same as the number of roots of $z$ in the unit disk, i.e., one... so the $P_n$'s are necessarily quadratic? Then fiddle with coefficients?

Comment: Think about how many roots $e^{P_n}$ has in the disk...

Comment: Oh, none. Whoops, I mixed up my argument principle on $e^{P_n(x)}$. That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: "Unicompactly" is, as far as I know, just a colloquial expression a friend invented. But I like it better than any of the alternatives.

Comment: I tend to like proofs better than theorems. If you like theorems better then do what Martin R says. Or apply Rouche. They're all really the same proof...

Comment: Then you really should modify the title. Using words you invented is not the best way to clue people in on what the question's about...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a sequence $(f_n)$ of entire functions satisfies $f_n(z) \to z$
uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb C$, then according to
[Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)), 
there is an $n_0$ such that  for $n \ge n_0$ each $f_n$ has exactly one zero in the
unit circle. This is surely not possible for
$f_n(z) = e^{P_n(z)}$.